# PHP MySQL using COUNT and WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the number of rows meeting certain criteria from a database.

I have a MySQL phpMyAdmin database called ovs and in it there's a table called results with 10 columns and a sample of 5 rows so far. The column I am interested in is named chairperson. I want to get the number of rows that have Tony Montana as the chairperson. How do I accomplish this?

This code of mine does not seem to work. It doesn't even output anything.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ovs");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE chairperson=Tony Montana";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("%d",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

This code does not seem to work. It doesn't even output anything. What is going on?

Comment: You need to quote the value to compare like `chairperson='Tony Montana'`

Comment: It's an SQL error as Tony Montana needs quote marks around it, escaped of course.  You might want to try displaying errors if you are in your development area - quickest way to spot a problem with SQL.

Comment: *"You might want to try displaying errors if you are in your development area "* @AdamWhateverson is right this is how you would do that  in PHP code `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Yeah, this just returns a 1, which is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should warp liter string value in quote

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE chairperson='Tony Montana';


$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results WHERE chairperson='Tony Montana';";
```